# How to do joining of tables and have all attributes of each one of them?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Assume you have two entities, one `Article` and the other one is `Fruits`. Now all the attributes of the entity `Article` is inherited by the entity `Fruits`.

So, lets say I have Article table with columns:

```
ART_ID
ART_NAME
ART_COST
```

and the Fruit table with columns:

```
FRU_ID
FRU_FROZEN
```

Now I want to make it possible in my JPA code, that when retrieving `Fruit` objects I retrieve all data that is supposed to be them, this data consisting of information from both my `Article` and `Fruit` tables -  `ART_ID`, `ART_NAME`, `ART_COST`, `FRU_ID`, `FRU_FROZEN`.

Is this possible in JPA? Should I use `@Inheritance`, `@JoinColumn` or what? If needed code can be provided.

---

*** EDIT ***

I have concluded that the code below will suit my needs:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Article")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Article {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ART_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ART_NAME")
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = true)
    @Column(name = "ART_COST")
    private String cost;  

    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Fruits")
@AttributeOverrides({
@AttributeOverride(name="name", column=@Column(name="ART_NAME")),
@AttributeOverride(name="cost", column=@Column(name="ART_COST")),
})
public class Fruits extends Article {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "FRU_ID")
    private Long fruitID;

    @Column(name="FRU_FROZEN")
    private String fruFrozen;

    //...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are your enties related at the database level? Association table? Foreign key relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is all your `Fruits` also `Article`s? If there is a real generalization (inheritance) relationship between the classes, use the @Inheritance with join table strategy.

And you can just query on `Fruits`, and Hibernate does all the magic.

By the way if you want to have a discriminator column in `Article`s table (a combination of join strategy with discriminator). Map it with single table strategy, and define a @SecondaryTable in your child class, that's how Hibernate supports it.

Comment: OK, for pointing me out I will award this answer with proposed one.